# Can somebody explain this to me about time complexity regarding the primality problem

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity, theory

We are covering the class P in my class and this one part is tripping me up regarding if the primality problem is in P

Our program:

```
"{prime(x): i =2; while i < x { if n mod i == 0 { return 0 } i++ } return 1 }"
```

Complexity for the program:
If x is n digits long, then x is in the rough vicinity of 10^n
. (Assuming no leading 0s, 10^n−1 ≤ x < 10^n.) The division algorithm that you learned
in elementary school divides an m-digit number by an n-digit number in
time O(mn). Puting that all together, we find that our algorithm for testing
whether an integer is prime takes time O(n^2 10^n).

My questions:
Where in the world does the professor get that x is 10^n, for example if x is 17 how does that turn into x being 10^2 = 100 operations long.
Furthermore where is the n^2 coming from in the final big O notation.

Comment: Yes,  primality problem (if `x` is *prime* or not) is in **P**, see **AKS test**: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AKS_primality_test

Answer (score 0):

This trial division algorithm has to try x−2 divisors (i.e.,
Θ(10<sup>n</sup>) of them) when x is prime. The vast majority of these
divisors have n or n−1 digits, so each division takes Θ(n<sup>2</sup>)
time on average since m = Θ(n).

Answer (score 0):

```
"{prime(x): i =2; while i < x { if n mod i == 0 { return 0 } i++ } return 1 }"
```

I mean with `n` you mean `x`, so your code should look like

```
prime(x){
    if(x == 2) return 0;
    for(int i = 2; i < x; i++)
        if(x mod i == 0) return 0
    return 1
}
```

This algorithm is the naive solution, which costs O(x).

It tests all natural numbers from 2 up to x. Supposing modulo is a constant time operation, you will do x - 1 operations (in worst case), hence O(x - 1) = O(x).

Obviously there are better solutions, like evaluating sieves to precompute primes so that you don't need to divide x for every other natural number.

Comment: Side note: `O(n)` in the *worst* case (when `x` is *prime*), `O(1)` in the *best* case (when `x` is *even*)

Comment: Side note: The routine returns `1` (`true`) for `x < 2` which is not correct: `0` and `1` are not primes

Answer (score 0):

Well, *primality problem* is in **P**, see [AKS Test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AKS_primality_test) for details

However, *naive algorithm* (that is in the question) is *not* in **P**. For given `x` we have

Time complexity `t = O(x)`:

```
{prime(x): 
   i = 2; 
   
   while i < x { # we loop x - 2 times, t = O(x) 
     if n mod i == 0 { 
       return 0 
     }

     i++ 
   } 
   
   return 1 
}
```

Size of the problem `s = O(log(x))` - we have to provide all *digits* to write `x`:

```
x = 123456789 # size is not 123456789, but 27 bits (or 9 digits)
```

So *time* complexity `t` from *size* of the problem `s` is `O(2^s)` if size `s` is in *bits* or `O(10^s)` if size `s` is in *decimal digits*. That is definitely *not polynomial*.

Let's have a look at your example: if `x` is `n` digits long (`log10(x)`), `t` will be `~ 10^n`:

```
                x : size (digits) :              time
 ----------------------------------------------------
               17 :  1.23         :                15 # your example
 ~ 17_000_000_000 : 10.23         :  ~ 17_000_000_000 # just 10 times longer
```

Can you see exponent `time ~ f(size)` now?

Answer (score 0):

> Where in the world does the professor get that x is 10^n

They don't.

What they actually said is:

> If x is n digits long, then x is **in the rough vicinity of** 10^n

In your case it's off by a factor of 100/17≈5.9. But that's a constant factor (and not a big one). In the worst case, it's off by factor 10. And in complexity classes we ignore such constant factors, so it doesn't matter for their analysis.